# Which Property type do I use to put a User's user_id() in the Datastore?

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore, identification

This is why I need to put user_id()'s in the Datastore:

> A User value in the datastore does not
>   get updated if the user changes her
>   email address. This may be remedied in
>   a future release. Until then, you can
>   use the User value's user_id() as the
>   user's stable unique identifier.
>
> http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/python/datastore/typesandpropertyclasses.html#users_User
>
> Within the datastore, the value is
>   equal to the email address plus the
>   user's unique ID. If the user changes
>   her email address, the new User value
>   will not equal the original User value
>   in datastore queries or when compared
>   by the app. If your app needs a stable
>   identifier that does not change, you
>   can store the unique ID separately
>   from the User value.
>
> http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/python/users/userobjects.html

How do I do it?

And how did you know (or where did you look it up?)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The usual answer is "no property": If you need a stable identifier, it's probably because you're looking users up by it, in which case you should use it as the key name for the entity, like so:

```
class UserInfo(db.Model):
  is_admin = db.BooleanProperty(required=True, default=False)

user_info = UserInfo.get_or_insert(users.get_current_user().user_id())
```

If you really need to store an identifier for the user elsewhere, you can use a db.StringProperty to store the User ID.